# How does Stack Overflow Careers evaluate GitHub profiles?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

When one registers for Stack Overflow Careers, one of the options it gives is to apply through one's GitHub profile. It will then inform the user whether the GitHub profile fits the bill for accepting the candidate into the careers programme.

How does it make that decision?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131652/what-are-the-rough-requirements-for-a-careers-account-via-github-and-shouldnt, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96799/in-careers-2-0-how-many-repos-needed-to-create-a-profile